# What is the meaning of < > in language specifications?

Tags: shell, command

When reading how to use certain commands I've come upon items that are wrapped in < >. I understand brackets denote optional but what is the meaning of these <>.

```
'git pull' [options] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, `<>` just denote named placeholders - these are helpful if e.g. more than one argument is optional or a name contains a space.

It is based on the [Backus–Naur Form (BNF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form), thanks to @etuardu for pointing this out!

Comment: Such notation is derived from the [Backus–Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)

Comment: okay but are these for options? option arguments? just arguments? I feel it is quite unclear how to interpret this specification and find little information online as to how to read.

Comment: @bmcentee148: Placeholders can be used anywhere. If you see `<foo>`, it usually means that you need to replace it with a specific "foo" (whatever "foo" happens to be).